# is it possible to add an existing angular project to new angular multiproject workspace?

Tags: angular, workspace, multiple-projects

condider i have project XYZ

in angular 6 we get new feature such as 
https://angular.io/guide/file-structure

Workspace and project file structure

it allows developer to use multiple projects as libraries or application where it creates sub folder named Projects and stores all sub projects in root prject ABC

now my question is,is it possible to add my existing project XYZ as sub project of ABC ??

i tried to do this i wasn't successful

i created sub project and with name XYZ and replace the code of sub project XYZ with my current XYZ projescts code